# Best practice for warning propagation in Perl

Tags: perl, logging, warnings

Is there an established best practice for handling different classes of warnings in a perl program, when logging, say, to syslog (or really any non-standard behavior)?

As an example, to send warnings to syslog:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    syslog(LOG_ERR,shift);
}
```

But now imagine that not all warnings are created equal.  Some should just be considered noise and demoted.  For instance, many MIME warnings aren't really indicative of a serious problem:

> ignoring text in character set `WINDOWS-1252'
>       at /usr/share/perl5/MIME/Parser/Filer.pm line 659

This would be better logged as, say `LOG_INFO`, or some other priority that doesn't alert the administrator to a problem, for instance.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

One easy solution might be:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my $msg = shift;
    my $prio = $msg =~ /(ignoring|Filer.pm)/ ? LOG_INFO : LOG_ERR;
    syslog($prio,$msg)
}
```

But this requires an (IMO) undesirably close coupling between my code and any libraries it calls, by having to carefully match warning messages... and it's also not very elegant or maintainable.

One possible solution I've seen which is a slight improvement, when I control the code, is to make sure my warnings all have a prefix:

```
warn "MIME parsing error: $@";
```

This makes the warning handler a bit simpler:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my $msg = shift;
    my $prio = $msg =~ /^MIME parsing error:/ ? LOG_INFO : LOG_ERR;
    syslog($prio,$msg)
}
```

But it still seems inelegant to do string-parsing on warnings to determine their classification.

Is there any more elegant solution? I'm looking for a generic best practice--even if it requires that all warning-emitting libraries be rewritten.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly to exception objects, you can introduce warning objects:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
    my $w = shift;
    if ($w->is_info) {
        print STDERR 'INFO:', $w->msg, "\n";
    }
};

warn 'My::Warning'->new( msg      => 'problem',
                         severity => 'info',
                        );
```

Comment: Is there a Warning class that does this already, or are you proposing I write one?

Comment: log4Perl works best, it also used in C, C++ and Java. (log for Perl) (http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Log-Log4perl-1.42/lib/Log/Log4perl.pm)

Comment: @alexmac: Do you want to make that an answer?

Comment: it is in  a way a hint, you can look up the docs.  It is a good habit, it is more standard and you don't have to hand roll anything.